# Why don't microwave oven transformers state their output voltage?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage

This is a simple question that I haven't found in anywhere before: Why don't MOTs state their output voltage?

I mean, I've been in a junkyard looking for MOTs and I've found about 30 MOTs of 5 different manufacturers maybe, none of them state their output voltage and neither does the info I found online about them (when I search their code only I only find the same info that's on their label again, input voltage, power, sometimes input current).

I know that measuring the primary-to-secondary ratio is damn simple, I just need to feed the secondary with line voltage instead and measure the primary, and I also know the output is < 2.1 kV because of the capacitor used.

But why don't they even mention it?

I couldn't be sure of what one had the highest output voltage while in the junkyard.

Comment: Why should they? They are an internal component inside the oven and not a generally reused part. They don't design m ovens so that someone can remove the transformer and reuse it.

Answer (score 5):

Microwave ovens are made in large numbers by many manufacturers. Each manufacturer has a specific circuit that requires a transformer with very specific requirements. These requirements will be laid out in a written specification that the manufacturer's vendors will bid on and the winning vendor will then produce that transformer to that specification. The transformer is intended only for use in microwave ovens.  It is not intended to be sold separately or to be re-used after the oven has completed its lifetime.  Thus there is no need for the transformer to have any markings indicating its operation. This is true of many components used in both commercial and military applications. It does  it harder for experimenters to salvage parts but that is the way it is.

Comment: Typically transformers are one of the easiest components to customize, and there's a big return for *having* them customized, so chances are a consumer item with a transformer will (A) be custom-made, and (B) have some in-house part number on it that tells you nothing about how it's built.

Answer (score 1):

Most general purpose transformers that we buy are approximations to an **Ideal Transformer**, which has a low impedance, constant voltage output. The more ideal the transformer, the better.

A MOT is not trying to be an ideal transformer. It has a large leakage inductance built into it, to resonate out some of the capacitive load that it drives. This relatively high impedance output means that the output voltage would depends on the load that was connected.

A MOT is a custom, system component. It only makes sense when embedded in the particular system it's been designed for. It doesn't therefore require parametric labeling, just a part number. The system includes the series output capacitor, the voltage doubler to the magnetron, and the fan-cooling that deals with its high current consumption whether on or off load.

Answer (score 0):

One old microwave oven I worked on at work had separate transformers for the filament and high voltage and did have the ratings: 2.1kV for the HV tranny, and 3.3V, but I don't remember the current for the filament one. 30A comes to mind, but that seems a bit much. Magnetron filaments are rated at around 10 or 11 amps. I measured about 2.4kV open cct. voltage on one transformer, using 2 DMMs in series and adding the readings.